# PHP 7.3 - count(NULL) makes php script to timeout

Tags: php, count, null, timeout

I have the following issue:

I moved some code from a PHP 7.1 server to an other with PHP 7.3.16.

In some scripts there was the **count** function for an array that **could be NULL**.

As per PHP [count() docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php):

> Return Values:
>
> Returns the number of elements in array_or_countable.
> When the parameter is neither an array nor an object with implemented
> Countable interface, 1 will be returned. There is one exception, if
> array_or_countable is NULL, 0 will be returned.

In PHP 7.1 all things were OK.

Now, in PHP 7.3 the script completely hangs in that line, until it timeouts.

Then, the following warning is thrown: *PHP Warning:  count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable*

The code that hangs always:

```html
<?php
  /* .... code  ..... */
  $array = null;  //this array becomes NULL
  
  $x = count($array);
  echo ''.$x;
```

I searched for it and found nothing. Thank you.

**A small update:**

The server above is Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

I tried the same in a CentosOS 7 server with PHP 7.3.15 an the function works as supposed to.

What can be wrong in Ubuntu?

Comment: You missed the bit on the manual page *7.2.0 count() will now yield a warning on invalid countable types passed to the array_or_countable parameter.*

Comment: Thank you for your answer @NigelRen. I am completely OK with the warning. It can help me to fix the code. The problem is that the script times out and finally stops in that line.

I also checked this page https://wiki.php.net/rfc/counting_non_countables.
I states that 'The call to count() will still return 1 (or 0 for null) so backwards compatibility is maintained. '

Comment: Without the code which may be causing the timeout, how can we know what the issue may be?

Comment: Excuse me, I just added the snippet.